# Multiple Bootstrap Modal issue with scroll bar

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

If i have two modals in my page and i open one after another and closes second one. it will remove scroll of the first modal. see demo http://learnkode.com/try/vUv3p4jQ please help me resolve this issue.

I want to have scroll as it is  for first modal after i close second modal(i should be able to look at header and footer of first modal).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MoralesBatovski i need to view header and footer of first modal. can you please look at my demo and help me.